# IOS grid using UITableviewcell

Tags: gridview, uitableview, ios6, grid

I want to create a grid view using `UITableView` and `UITableViewCell` customization, because for each row i want to display a background image for the row.

please help me to find a solution other than collection view.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very complicated problem that has a multitude of solutions. You have several options:

- create a tableview cell with several view arranged horizontally to emulate a "column" experience. This is best if you have a fixed number of columns you want
- implement a tableview cell which contains a horizontal tableview (a uitableview flipped on its side) where you rotate the individual cell the opposite direction of the horizontal table view. This is great if you have a variable number of columns per row, but all the rows will be independently scrolling unless you take steps to avoid that.
- finally implement your own grid experience that sort of emulates the uitableview experience of reusable cells. (but that is outside the question parameters)

I could go into detail if one of these options appeals to you.

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement you need to display a **GridView**

So to support earlier versions and get other cool features you can use other libraries here are some of the options:

1) [KKGridView](https://github.com/kolinkrewinkel/KKGridView)

2) [UIGridView](https://github.com/tanin47/UIGridView)

3) [AQGridView](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView)

4) [NRGridView](https://github.com/ldesroziers/NRGridView)

5) [MMGridView](https://github.com/provideal/MMGridView)

6) [WCGridView](https://github.com/wess/WCGridView)

I am currently using **`AQGridView`** so surely i recommend that as it is the least buggy and its functions are very similar to `UITableView`.

Also that If you are trying to do this without **XIB** it will be little bit difficult for you to handle it but you can create a view controller with Xib file to Create the interface of your choice. [Here is the Video of how it can be done in the best possible way](http://vimeo.com/46408155) by  `Evadne Wu`. And [here](https://github.com/evadne/gridViewNibTest) is the Sample Project